# logarithmic color scale

Tags: qgis, color, colormap

I am using QGIS Essen on Windows 10. I have a data set (.txt file) that contains latitude, longitude, and black carbon (BC) values. I can style the layer using the values of BC - graduated style, color ramp. As such: 
[image]

However, I would like to have the colors in log scale so I can still distinguish between the different low values (yellow dots). As you can see on the right side, all is just yellow. Is there a way to do this?

Update: I tried again the field calculator approach and got a nice plot. However, I would like the color ramp "logged" and not the values (please let me know if this makes sense). I'm trying to achieve something like this that I have done in Igor (but the graphics is better in QGIS): [image]

As you can see, the color scale is also logged. Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @honeyace4! You could use the **Field Calculator** to create a new field using a `log()` expression with values from your "BC" field and then style the layer using this field.

Comment: What style are you using now? If you use natural breaks (jenks) it should spread out many close values into more categories.

Comment: @Joseph - I tried using the Field Calculator but it is giving me weird results. Maybe I wasn't using it correctly.

Comment: @HDunn - I have actually tried playing with all the styles. The natural breaks option spread out the vertical line nicely, but not the yellow parts on the left side.

Comment: If you want help troubleshooting your efforts using the Field Calculator, edit your post to include what formulas you've tried.

Comment: I think, in the second example an unclassified "style" is used. Never seen a function doing that in GIS for vector data, only for raster.

Comment: Two layers; one for the map, one for the legend. Logged values on the map, linear values on the scale.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that easily. Go to properties of the layer, select "graduated" style and write a function like "log10("YOURATTRIBUTE")". Then classify you values.

[image]

[image]

[image]